# (T-SQL) Did daylight savings occur in the last hour?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have a process that is going to use table partitioning (each partition is 1 hour) and I need to handle the daylight savings flips when archiving out the data.

For instance, this past weekend it went from 1:59:59 to 1:00:00, so the second time that the partitioning code ran at 1:05am nothing would occur - the midnight hour had already been SWITCHed out.

However, when spring rolls around, the time goes from 1:59am to 3:00am, so when the job runs at 3:05, it would SWITCH out 2am.... leaving the data from the 1am hour in the original table.

In theory I can just look for the oldest not-current partition with data and flip that one (partition key is a default getdate() constraint), but I was wondering if there was some way to use AT TIME ZONE to determine that daylight savings had "occurred", so that we could have different code to handle that older hour still being out there.

Thanks.

Comment: This past weekend it went from 1:59:59 to 1:00:00, did it not? Maybe my timezone works differently than yours? What does "It flips 2am" mean? What is "It" in that context and what does "Flip" mean? It's getting late in the day here, so I'm probably just struggling to understand obvious things. If that's the case, I'm very sorry.

Comment: This is not really very clear. But a person's timezone doesn't change at daylight saving reversal. If they are in PST they are still in PST. It is that the local time jumps an hour (back in the Fall and forward in the Spring). Not really sure what your question is here. Are you partitioning your table on the hour?

Comment: You can use the DATEPART(TZ,@DateTimeOffsetValue) to get the offset. I bet you could get a DateTimeOffset AT TIME ZONE '<server time zone>' for two values and compare the offsets for a change, unfortunately, that would require you to know the time zone of the server in advance. Perhaps there is a way to normalize around UTC and check for a difference, that way you do not need to know the server time zone.

Comment: In short: use UTC. No time zones, no DTS, none of that mess. Problem solved.

Comment: @JNevill fixed it for clarity.  We refer to the SWITCH as a "flip". And I realize that you're still in the same "time zone", but I'd think there's some way to differentiate, since there are states (and in some cases, cities) that behave differently compared to others.

Comment: @RossBush I'll give that a shot; DATEPART(TZ) is probably what I was looking for.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes, UTC. Which would technically work but isn't what's I'm asking for.  Appreciate the mention of UTC, though.

Comment: @SeanLange exactly, we're doing the SWITCH every hour so that we can get it into a clustered columnstore ASAP for compression (10x vs 3x using PAGE).

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this.  Basically take your current getdate() and use AT TIME ZONE with any time zone that observes.   Then use DATEPART tz and compare your current and before.

Regardless of what the server time zone is, using AT TIME ZONE will get you the offset for a particular datetime value in that time zone.

For comparison of before I think you'd need to use 2 hours, 1 for the switch and 1 for how far back you want to check.

Give this a look:

```
DECLARE @BeforeDate DATETIME = '2018-11-04 1:59' --Before the change
DECLARE @AfterDate DATETIME = '2018-11-04 3:00' --After the change

--use can use AT TIME ZONE with DATEPART tz which tells you offset in minutes
--I'm in central, any should work for any that observe the time change
--Your offset is different because of the change.

SELECT DATEPART(tz, @BeforeDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time')
SELECT DATEPART(tz, @AfterDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time')

--using the above you could possibly compare current offset to 2 hours prior to see if they changed.  2 hours, 1 for the switch and 1 for how far back you want to compare.
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME = '2018-11-04 3:00'  --"simulate" getdate() as of the time change

DECLARE @PriorOffSet INT = (SELECT DATEPART(tz, DATEADD(HOUR, -2, @CurrentDate) AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time')) --You'd have to subtract 2 hours to account for the hour shift and the hour back you want to check.
DECLARE @CurrentOffset INT = (SELECT DATEPART(tz, @CurrentDate AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'))

SELECT @PriorOffSet, @CurrentOffset

IF @PriorOffSet <> @CurrentOffset
    SELECT 'Time changed in the last hour'
ELSE
    SELECT 'No time change in the last hour'
```